# В чем разница при обращении к объекту другого класса

Tags: java

Так-с, есть 3 класса.

- 1-ый `SqliteTest` - для запуска
- 2-ой `SqliteConnector` - устанавливает соединение
- 3-ий `CreateMetods` - сборник методов

Я могу инициализировать `SqliteConnector` в классе `SqliteTest`, передать его экземпляр в метод из `CreateMetods`, и все будет работать. Но если я попытаюсь создать `SqliteConnector` в самом классе `CreateMetods`, то выдает ошибку NullPointerException.

С чем это связано, почему так принципиально создать объект в классе, где есть main? Или быть может я просто неправильно создаю?

**Код, основное выделено "// Здесь"**

**SqliteTest:**

```
import java.sql.*; 

public class SqliteTest{
    public static void main (String... args) throws SQLException{
        
        SqliteConnector sqliteConnector = new SqliteConnector();  // Здесь
        CreateMetods createMetods=new CreateMetods();  // Здесь
        sqliteConnector.openConnection();
        sqliteConnector.createStatement();
        createMetods.createTable("name", "c0 int");  // Здесь
        sqliteConnector.closeConnection();
        System.out.println("End");
    }   
}
```

**SqliteConnector:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

class SqliteConnector{
    
    Connection connectorA;
    Statement  statementA;    // Здесь
    
    Statement getStatementA (){
        return statementA;
    }
    
    void createStatement () throws SQLException{      // Здесь
        statementA=connectorA.createStatement();
    }
    
    void openConnection (){
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connectorA=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db\\A.db");
            System.out.println("Connected");
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    void closeConnection (){
        try{
            connectorA.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    
}
```

**CreateMetods:**

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CreateMetods{
    SqliteConnector sqliteConnector; // Здесь
    
    CreateMetods (){      // Здесь

        sqliteConnector = new SqliteConnector();
    }
    
    void createTable (String name, String column) throws SQLException{   
        String query="CREATE TABLE  "+name+"  ("+column+");";
        sqliteConnector.statementA.executeUpdate(query);    // Здесь
        
        System.out.println("Таблица создана");
    } //создание таблицы
}
```

[image: 3 класс]

Comment: А на какой собственно строке NullPointerException?

Comment: in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at CreateMetods.createTable
                          В этом методе на строке "sqliteConnector.statementA.executeUpdate(query);"
Это 3ий по счету класс

Comment: Сейчас добавлю скриншот,думаю,так понятнее будет

Comment: Да, было бы норм

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В приведённом коде не видно, чтобы нужный экземпляр класса `SqliteConnector` *передавался* в `CreateMethods`.

Сейчас создаётся, но не используется полностью готовый экземпляр:

```
SqliteConnector sqliteConnector = new SqliteConnector();
sqliteConnector.openConnection();
sqliteConnector.createStatement();
```

И создаётся и используется "пустой" экземпляр в конструкторе `CreateMethods`:

```
sqliteConnector = new SqliteConnector();
```

Именно из "пустого" экземпляра Вы и пытаетесь вытянуть нулевой `statementA`:

```
sqliteConnector.statementA.executeUpdate(query);
```

Что бы сделал я:

1. Не создавал бы экземпляр класса `SqliteConnector` в `SqliteTest`.
2. В конструкторе `CreateMethods` создал бы полностью готовый (тот, что выполнил методы `openConnection()` и `createStatement()`)
   экземпляр класса `SqliteConnector`.

Comment: То есть нужно либо каждый раз заполнять объект sqliteConnector для каждого класса, либо передавать в метод класса уже заполненный? А что если сделать объект sqliteConnector статическим, чтобы заполнить его только один раз, а затем использовать везде: или так не стоит делать из-за какого-нибудь ООП правила?

Comment: Конечно, в примере не видно, чтобы `sqliteConnector` использовался бы где-нибудь ещё. Но чтобы с ним можно было работать из других классов, разумеется, придётся им передавать экземпляр.

Comment: [Лучше об этом не думать] Засуньте все методы в конструктор `SqliteConnector` и организуйте [Singleton](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/27108/)

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь Мр